# Issue on ArcGIS SOAP NAServer Namespace

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-soap-api

I am trying to create a simple ArcGIS Server SOAP consumer by C# like below snippet  but I am getting error on `NAService_NAServer`as illustrated in attached image. Can you please let me know which namespace I have to use?

[image]

I am already using this namespaces

> ```
> using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
> using ESRI.ArcGIS.Server;
> using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
> using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
> using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
> ```

but they are not doing the job!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Server;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            private void SolveRoute()
        {
            // Connect to server
            NAService_NAServer naService = new NAService_NAServer();
            naService.Url = "http://localhost/ArcGIS/services/NetworkAnalysisService/MapServer/NAServer");
            //Get Route layers
            string[] routeLayers = naService.GetNALayerNames(esriNAServerLayerType.esriNAServerRouteLayer);

            // Get the default settings for the first route layer
            NAServerRouteParams naServerRouteParams = (NAServerRouteParams)naService.GetSolverParameters(routeLayers[0]);

            // Create 2 stops as property sets
            List<PropertySet> propertySets = new List<PropertySet>(2);
            propertySets.Add(CreatePropertySet("My starting point", -117.195905, 34.057783));
            propertySets.Add(CreatePropertySet("My ending point", -117.180943, 34.056286));

            // Set the property sets on a NAServerPropertySets object and set on the routeParams object
            NAServerPropertySets naServerPropertySets = new NAServerPropertySets();
            naServerPropertySets.PropertySets = propertySets.ToArray();
            naServerRouteParams.Stops = naServerPropertySets;

            // specify to return compact directions
            naServerRouteParams.ReturnCompactDirections = true;

            // Solve
            NAServerRouteResults naServerRouteResults = (NAServerRouteResults)naServer.Solve(naServerRouteParams);

            // Output directions
            NACompactStreetDirections streetDirections = naServerRouteResults.CompactDirections[0];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("DriveTime = {0}", streetDirections.Summary.TotalDriveTime);
            sb.AppendLine();
            foreach (NACompactStreetDirection streetDirection in streetDirections.Directions)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(streetDirection.Text);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The namespace depends on what you defined the namespace when added the service reference.
For example:

- I created a new .NET App named "RouteUsingSOAP"
- Right-click on the project and click on "Add > Service Reference"
- Specify the Address to the SOAP endpoint.  In my case: 
  http://mymachine:6080/arcgis/services/Routing/NetworkAnalysis/MapServer/NAServer?wsdl
- Specify the Namespace by putting "NAServer"
- Click OK to create the service.

And then the following code works for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RouteUsingSOAP.NAServer.NAServerPortClient naService = new RouteUsingSOAP.NAServer.NAServerPortClient();
  string[] routeLayers = naService.GetNALayerNames(NAServer.esriNAServerLayerType.esriNAServerRouteLayer);
  foreach (string layerName in routeLayers) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(layerName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the NASever class was [depreciated at 10.1](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#naserver.htm).

> At version 10.1, ArcGIS for Server no longer supports performing
>   network analysis via local connections using the GISServer and
>   GISClient APIs. Use the SOAP or REST API instead.